# Is there any "fundamental" uncertainty to the timing of the Big Bang?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, big-bang

I wondered whether, under the probabilistic interpretations of QM, the *timing* of the Big Bang (or perhaps any other historical event) is *fundamentally* as uncertain as (or: like) other (e.g., future) quantum-mechanical processes. That is, looking backwards, should one—*if one insists on being pedantic about it*—actually treat the Big Bang as a superposition of many "possible" (and interfering) Big Bangs?

Comment: I think it's quite tricky to mix QM and GR.

Comment: @jinawee If you think it's tricky, you might focus on the "any other historical event" part.